# make the two parallels lines vertically at the center of an content from left and right

Tags: html, css, center, vertical-alignment

I am facing one issue, maybe not a big one but I am not able to figure out how can I do

I want the `double line` in between the content of a div `left (Subtotal)` and `right ($200)`.
Can anyone help me with this?

I have tried but I am not able to make it vertically middle.

Attaching screenshot of how I want it to look:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WD57Y.png)

**CODE SNIPPET I AHVE TRIED:**

```css
.row{
  display: flex;
}

.dividerLine{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: right;
    border: 2px solid red;
    height: 7px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">  
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3 start-lines">
          <p class="order-receipt-label light-label">   
            <span>Subtotal</span>
          </p>
      </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 dividerLine" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
    
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 start-lines">
       <p class="order-receipt-label light-label">                       
          <span>Subtotal</span>
       </p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

product total and I want to make the double line in between them
Attaching the screenshot how it looks:

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by giving `.row` the `align-items: center;` property and removing `margin` from the `p` tags inside `.start-lines`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS flex align center option for this.

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.mb-0 {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
.dividerLine {
    border-top: 2px solid red;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    height: 7px;
    background-color: lavenderblush;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
          <p class="order-receipt-label light-label mb-0">   
            <span>Subtotal</span>
          </p>
      </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="dividerLine"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
       <p class="order-receipt-label light-label mb-0"> 
          <span>Subtotal</span>
       </p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a giant equals sign, so let's make it a giant equals sign. That way we can be sure that it will align with the other characters vertically correctly without us having to do any other vertical positioning.

The way this can be done is to put an = character in the central column at the standard font-size but scale in the x direction. We put a huge scale in just so it will cover the whole central column whatever the width. Of course this isn't seen as overflow is set to hidden.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
p.wide-font {
  transform: scale(10000, 1);
  color: gold;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3" style="text-align: right;">
      <p style="text-align: right;">SUBTOTAL</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="overflow: hidden;">
      <p class="wide-font">=</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">        
      <p style="text-align: left;">SUBTOTAL</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```